# Air-Augmentation on a VTO&L super heavy lift

Tags: rockets, engines, design-alternative

I'm working on a basic design for an Air-Augmented first stage, which boosts the second, expendable, stage from a near-orbit, to allow for deorbit of the second stage.
Essentially it's an SSTO that uses a second stage so that it can land again...

Is it feasible to use radial air-breathing engines for the time it spends inside the thicker atmosphere, before switching to closed cycle.
LH2/LOX at max efficiency for closed cycle, HOTOL-esque engines for air-breathing ascent.
Please tell me why I shouldn't try this.
Thanks

Also:
HOTOL engine:http: //www.astronautix.com/h/hotol.html
Similar design to: //www.astronautix.com/n/novammr10e-2.html

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "radial airbreathing engines"? The term usually applies to piston engines.

Comment: @Woody they reference HOTOL which apparently was at least partially an [air breathing jet engine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Aerospace_HOTOL) but also closed cycle once it leaves the lower atmosphere, like in the question. The OP seems to be more or less asking about the same-ish engine as that project

Comment: @fyrepenguin ... thanks for the link. But it doesn't clarify the "radial" term. I'm still mystified.

Comment: Good point, @Woody. Possibly they’re conflating radial/piston engines with jet engines?  Or they’ve got a totally different idea that the OP should elaborate on & clarify things.

Comment: I don’t understand the first paragraph at all. It’s SSTO but has a second stage, the second stage is expendable but deorbits?

Comment: @Woody That was unclear of me; I meant radially arranged, and airbreathing as in intake oxygen as combustion oxidiser.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I was meaning that it is designed like an SSTO, but isn't pushed to that performance limit, allowing for higher payload mass by utilising a second stage for orbit completion

Comment: Of potential interest, a design study for a jet-boosted launcher, which drops the jet engines for parachute recovery at ~15km.  https://yarchive.net/space/launchers/jet_first_stage.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have actual numbers for your air-breathing engines and rocket, do a trade study.  How much velocity do you expect to get out of your air-breathing stage?  How much does it (and whatever associated systems of ducting/shielding, pylons, fuel lines, etc) weigh?  How much would the rocket fuel to get you to that velocity weigh?

I suspect that even this first-order trade would indicate you're better off just sticking with rockets.

There are other considerations too, but so far air launch hasn't been a big winner in rocketry, and launching from a carrier aircraft gives you the added bonus of not having to carry all that extra mass to orbit.  That's not to say there's no scenario where this works out (the industry scoffed at reusability for a long while because of how expensive Shuttle was to run) but no one has showed convincing numbers.